# Add a form helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

Ive made a nice editor in jQuery and i want to add it as a form helper method.

how would i go about making a new form helper method?

ideally id like to be able to call:

```
f.nice_editor :field
```

Comment: Can you provide some more specifics? Do you want to be able to do something like "f.nice_editor :foo" within a "form_for @foo do |f|" block?

Comment: Yeah, thats what im going for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object yielded to `form_for` is an instance of `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`. So all you have to do is to add instance methods there.

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def custom_field(...)
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Part of the question is: where do you put the nice_editor code? I don't think it is a good idea to directly edit class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder in your installation. Instead, put your code in one of the files in app/helpers. There are several ways to add extension methods to FormBuilder.

For instance, suppose you have a helper file items_helper.rb:

```
module ItemsHelper
    # this is one way to define new instance methods
    ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.class_eval do
        def nice_editor(conf,*opts)
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

Also, see this [good discussion](http://st-on-it.blogspot.com/2008/10/writting-own-form-helper-for-rails.html), which shows how to use self.included() to extend FormBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

after some research i found that this works:

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    def nice_editor(conf)
         #stuff to draw the editor
    end
end
```

"conf" would have all the symbol options passed to it from the view. it works fine with f.