# How to add a default class to text_field in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

How to change default generated code for rails form helpers?

Code...

```
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'inputbox' %>
```

...generates...

```
<input id="post_title" name="post[title]" class="inputbox" type="text">
```

...but I would like that text_field without class argument generated code above by default.

I am using rails 3.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to get this behavior you will either have to overwrite the existing text field method or add a new method that does what you want. I would recommend the latter since you won't be changing the existing behavior of a built-in Rails method.

Similar to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128114/add-a-form-helper-method):

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def inputbox_field(method, options = {})
    text_field(method, options.merge(class: 'inputbox'))
  end
end
```

Then you would just change you view to use this instead:

```
<%= f.inputbox_field :title %>
```

Comment: Please, just a newbie question: Where can I put this code? in which file and in which folfer?

Comment: @AlbertCatalà I'm not totally sure the best place, but you could stick it directly in an initializer or in lib/inputbox_field.rb and require it in application.rb after Bundler.require